# Date Bookmark linked to Date Picker in WORD Template always populates as "30 Dec 1899"

Tags: vba, date, ms-word, bookmarks

I have developed several related WORD macro-enabled templates using VBA. They all use common programming and bookmarks (i.e. bookmark names and VBA code to populate the bookmarks.) As I have progressed in learning how to design/program the templates, I have added more advanced features. One new feature was using a Date Picker instead of a text box where the user typed in the date.  I have successfully incorporated the Date Picker into all the templates...except one...the first one I developed. The date bookmark associated with the Date Picker for that one always populates as "30 Dec 1899" instead of the date selected on the Date Picker. This occurs event when the Date Picker is disabled.

I have queried ChatGPT with every possible variation on pertinent questions I can think of. I have implemented all the various coding suggestions with no success. I have ensured the Date Picker is properly initialized and enabled on the UserForm. I know that Microsoft Office uses 30 Dec 1899 as its "base date". This leads me to think the issue is with the document's formatting or properties not the VBA coding. I have used the same workstation and WORD app to develop all the templates, so I do not think it is a setting/property with the computer or the App itself.

I am wondering if anyone has a suggestion on how to view the really detailed settings, properties and/or formatting for a WORD document, I would appreciate it.

Here is the VBA code I've successfully used to populate the Date bookmarks in the other templates that are working correctly.  (There are a couple variants to the bookmarks because they appear in different places within the template and used differing formats in those locations):

```
Dim Selected_Date As Range
Set Selected_Date = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Selected_Date").Range
Selected_Date.Text = Format(Me.Date_Picker.Value, "dd Mmm yy")

Dim Selected_Date_1 As Range
Set Selected_Date_1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Selected_Date_1").Range
Selected_Date_1.Text = Format(Me.Date_Picker.Value, "Mmm yy")

Dim Selected_Date_2 As Range
Set Selected_Date_2 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Selected_Date_2").Range
Selected_Date_2.Text = Format(Me.Date_Picker.Value, "Mmm yy")
```

Here are some examples of the coding suggestions that did not correct the problem

'Suggestion 1'

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
DTPicker1.Format = dtpCustom
DTPicker1.CustomFormat = "dd MM yyyy"
DTPicker1.Value = Date
End Sub
```

'Suggestion 2'

```
Private Sub CommandButtonOk_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument
Call UpdateBookmark("CDOB", Format(TextBoxCDOB.Value, "d MMM yyyy"))
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help you debug code that isn’t working when you haven’t included it in your question? You don’t say which version of Word you are using but have you consided using a date picker content control instead? If you use the Publish Date found under Insert | Quick Parts | Document Properties you can have it appear in multiple places but only need to set it in one.

Comment: Could the bookmark name have a zero instead of an "O" (or vice versa) in its name?

Comment: The question did not pertain to the VBA code…I am asking about  “looking under the hood” to find any hidden or not obvious formatting and/or properties in the document that might be causing the problem. The code works perfectly in several other templates.

Comment: Posting code that is used in other templates is entirely irrelevant to your question.  There are no formatting options or properties that would cause the issue. The only relevant factors are the code that you are using *in that document* and the name of the bookmark in that document.

Comment: The code I posted WAS used in my problem template! I'm sensing some entirely unwarranted hostility Timothy Rylatt.  I am a new VBA user and don't have ANY formal coding training AT ALL.  All my experience is OJT, so if I offended your delicate coder sensibilities by asking questions that are not perfectly phrased I apologize. I have consulted with a vastly experienced IT professional in my company and he is stumped as well.  I turned to this forum for help and all I got was a ration of $h!t from you. Please refrain from "helping" me any further on this or other posts I might make.

Comment: Jonsson, I will check for the zero versus an "O" in the bookmark name.  Don't think so, but I will ensure that is not the case.

Comment: To clarify, the coding I provided above that worked in the other templates is exactly the same code I used in the problem template.  I've checked it character by character.  A very experienced IT-certified co-worker has done the same with no resolution.   Is there anywhere else in the VBA coding (i.e. for the document itself versus the UserForm) that could cause this conflict.  (Timothy Rylatt, resist the urge to reply)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.